# How to use MS MPI with Clion

Tags: c++, c, mpi, clion, ms-mpi

i try to use MS MPI with the Clion ide.
The msmpisdk.msi and the msmpisetup is already installed.
How can i include the MS MPI sdk in Clion?

Thanks for your Help